# Does Github Actions support anything but Ubuntu?

Tags: github-actions

I see in my Github actions

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

What other distros are available? For example, can I run on Alpine or Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

Github only supports Ubuntu as of 2024 (and osx, and windows). You can see the list of supported runners for

- [public repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#standard-github-hosted-runners-for-public-repositories)
- [private repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#standard-github-hosted-runners-for-private-repositories)

You can find the [source code for the runners here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images).